# Count clock cycles from assembly source code?

Tags: performance, analysis

I have the source code written and I want to measure efficiency as how many clock cycles it takes to complete a particular task. Where can I learn how many clock cycles different commands take? Does every command take the same amount of time on 8086?

Answer (score 2):

[RDTSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is the high-resolution clock fetch instruction.

Bear in mind that cache misses, context switches, instruction reordering and pipelining, and multicore contention can all interfere with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Clock cycles and efficiency are not the same thing.

For efficiency of code you need to consider, in particular, how the memory is utalised, in particular the differing levels of the cache.  Also important is the branching prediction of the code etc.  You want a profiler that tells you these things, ideally one that gives you profile specific information:  examples are CodeAnalyst for AMD chips.

To answer your question, particular base instructions do have a given (average) number of cycles (AMD release the approximate numbers for the basic maths functions in their maths library).  These numbers are a poor place to start optimising code, however.

Comment: I'm using this as a true measurement of speed. Any purely software task should not simply be timed by seconds or minutes when not on a dedicated system. I'm writing an encryption and I want to know how many clock cycles it takes to encrypt each byte. I can't measure in MB/s because different grades of computers are returning speeds between 50 MB/s and 350 MB/s. Many encryption algorithms' "speeds" are measured this way.

Comment: @Corey Ah I see, particular functions in the AMD library have the clock cycles documented, if that helps (ch 7): developer.amd.com/assets/acml_userguide.pdf